# Form is resetting when clicking on GO Button in HTC flyer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an application developed using Phonegap. When I am submitting my HTML form by clicking on HTC Flyer's GO Button, the form is resetting instead of submitting. I searched over internet. But I couldn't fine this type of questions or answers. Please help me out.

```
<link href="css/form.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/iscroll-lite.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqFancyTransitions.1.8.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="config.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/service.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/menu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/modules/slideshow.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/modules/device.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/modules/register.js"></script>
<div class="box module" id="box_register">
 <div class="box_content">
<form id="loginForm" >
  <div class="box_content_tab">Register</div>
    <div class="box_content_center">
      <div class="form_content">
    <label>Name</label>
      <input id="registerNameFld" type="text" class="form_input_box" />
                <label>Email</label>
              <input id="registerEmailFld" type="text" class="form_input_box" />
                 <label>Password</label>
              <input id="registerPasswordFld" type="password" class="form_input_box" />
                 <label>Confirm Password</label>
               <input id="confirmPasswordFld" type="password" class="form_input_box" />
         <div id="registerBtn" class="form-btn blue-btn" >Submit</div>
              </div>
        </div>
         </form>
     </div>
   </div>
 <script>
$("#box_register").newAccount();
</script>
```

And my register.js file is

```
(function($) {
$mod = null;
registerMod = {
 initialize : function() {
   $mod.center();
   $('#registerBtn').click(
    function() {
     if ($("#registerNameFld").val() == ''
       || $("#registerEmailFld").val() == ''
       || $("#registerPasswordFld").val() == ''
       || $('#confirmPasswordFld').val() == '') {
         if($("#registerNameFld").val() == ''
            && $("#registerEmailFld").val() == ''
            && $("#registerPasswordFld").val() == ''
            && $('#confirmPasswordFld').val() == ''){
                alert('Please enter All Fields');
          }
         else if($("#registerNameFld").val() == ''){
            alert('Please enter Username ');
          }
         else if($("#registerEmailFld").val() == ''){
            alert('Please enter Email ');
          }
         else if($("#registerPasswordFld").val() == ''){
             alert('Please enter Password ');
          }
         else if($("#confirmPasswordFld").val() == ''){
             alert('Please enter Confirm Password ');
          }
        }else {
          if(registerMod.isNameValid($("#registerNameFld").val()) == 'correct'){
           if(registerMod.isEmailValid($("#registerEmailFld").val()))
           {
            if($("#registerPasswordFld").val().length >= 6){
             if(registerMod.isPassValid($("#registerPasswordFld").val()) == 'correct'){
              if( $("#registerPasswordFld").val() == $('#confirmPasswordFld').val()){
               if($("#registerPasswordFld").val() ==$("#registerNameFld").val()){
                 alert('Name and Password should not be same');
               }
               else{
                 service.newAccount({
                 name : $("#registerNameFld").val(),
                 email : $("#registerEmailFld").val(),
                 password : $("#registerPasswordFld").val(),
                 device : device
               }, registerMod.onRegisterSuccess, registerMod.onRegisterError);    
             }
             }else{
               alert("Your password and confirmation password do not match.");
             }
       }else if(registerMod.isPassValid($("#registerPasswordFld").val()) == 'special'){
         alert('Password should not contain only special characters');
       }else if(registerMod.isPassValid($("#registerPasswordFld").val()) =='space'){
         alert('Password should not contain spaces');
       }else{
         alert('invalid format of password');
       }
      }
      else{
        alert('Password should contain minimum 6 characters');
      }
     }
     else{
       alert('Please enter valid Email address');
     }
    }
    else if(registerMod.isNameValid($("#registerNameFld").val())=='special'){
    alert('Name should not contain special characters');
     }
  else if(registerMod.isNameValid($("#registerNameFld").val())=='number'){
     alert('Name should not contain only numbers and should not start with numbers');
   }
 else if(registerMod.isNameValid($("#registerNameFld").val())=='invalid'){
     alert('Name should not start with Space');
 }
 }
    return false;
 });
    },
    onRegisterSuccess : function(rep) {
        $('#box_register').fadeOut();
        app.onLogin(rep);
    },
    onRegisterError : function() {
        app.onError();
        alert("Email was already taken");
    },
    isEmailValid:function (mailID) {
        var atpos=mailID.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos=mailID.lastIndexOf(".");
        if(atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=mailID.length){   
            return false; 
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    },
    isNameValid:function (name) {
        var regexCorrect = /^[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*[!@#$%\^&*(){}[\]<>?\/\-'".,;:+_]*/;
        var regexSpl = /[!@#$%\^&*(){}[\]<>?\/\-'".,;:+_]/;
        var regexNum = /^\d+/;
        if(regexCorrect.test(name)){
            return "correct";
        }else if(regexSpl.test(name)){
            return "special";
        }else if(regexNum.test(name)){
            return "number";
        }else{
            return "invalid";
        }
    },
    isPassValid:function (name) {
        var regSpace = /[\s]/;
        var regexSpl = /^[!@#$%\^&*(){}[\]<>?\/\-'".,;:+_]$/;
        if(regSpace.test(name)){
            return 'space';
        }else if(regexSpl.test(name)){
            alert('matching');
            return 'special';
        }else{
            return 'correct';
        }
    }
};

$.fn.newAccount = function() {
    $mod = $(this);
    registerMod.initialize();
};

})(jQuery);
```

service is defined in service.js file

Comment: What are you expecting? You have a form element, but no action and no method attributes, so if you had a submit button it would just do a get to the same page the form is on, which is exactly what is happening. You don't even have a submit, though, just some JavaScript wiring. What does the JavaScript do? Does it call the submit method on the form? Does it build an AJAX request based on the values? Are you running the page locally inside the app, or remotely from a URL? If you are submitted to a remote URL in JavaScript, have you added the proper access element in the PhoneGap config?

Comment: I wrote all the action stuff in register.js. I included that file. register.js file contains validations as well as service calls. Should I include that file here?

Comment: using the id value of the submit div I am validating all the fields. when ever all the fields are true for the conditions, the data has to be submitted through AJAX request. At that time only, I have the problem with HTC device's GO button. the data can be submitted with the submit div in the code but cannot be submitted with device button. When ever I am using device button, the form is resetting or reloading.

Comment: Ah, I see that problem happen on web sites a lot too, where people replace the HTML form submit with their own JavaScript, then hitting enter in a field reloads the page instead of triggering their JavaScript, since it is triggering the real form submit and not their JavaScript. Why not put your Javascript logic in an onsubmit handler, cancel the default handling, and do your custom handling? That's a good idea on the web as well, by the way.